# Why is terminating mobile apps managed by the OS, instead of the user?

Tags: android, ios

On desktop an application becomes terminated by the user. On mobile this usage is intended. Terminating apps is usually done by the OS, when memory becomes short.

But **what's the reason for the mobile-approach?** Why have Google and Apple chosen, that terminating app has to be handled by the OS?

Comment: Related: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory-management

Comment: Because mobile devices typically have much less available memory. If it was left up to the user to terminate apps, and they didn't, then the device would run out of memory and start terminating apps anyway; the alternative to terminating apps would be to send notifications to the user telling them that they need to quit some apps.  This would just be annoying. Letting the operating system handle and it have apps restore their state when they relaunch hides all of this from the user.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Thanks for the link. The article is great.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks. If you like: Turn your comment to an answer. I will accept it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Why don't Android and iOS kill the process when the app is closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55703963/295004)